# Relevant part of a question removed, now my answer gets downvoted

Tags: support

For my first [answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24482/what-is-a-gameplay-programmer/110468#110468) on this site, I had found a question where only the first part had been answered, and the second ignored. I answered the second part. Now, the question has been edited to remove the second part, and my answer is getting downvoted.

What do I do? Should I delete the now-extraneous answer? Can I recover my negative "game industry" score?

Comment: would you consider posting a link to that question? or your answer?

Comment: My guess of what happened: You answered a very old question that was off topic. It showed up in the activity log. It has been flagged as off topic. It's been been edited to be brought back more on topic; the most off-topic part has been removed, and unfortunately, it's on that your answered, making the answer off topic. And that resulted in your downvotes.

Comment: I would assume that deleting the answer should revert the reputation, but I can't confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three of the downvotes on your answer occurred before or while I was editing the question itself, so I don't think that the portions of your answer that address the part of the question I removed were really the basis for the those downvotes (which as I write this constitute the majority; your answer has +1 and -4 overall).

I removed the portion of the question asking how one becomes a gameplay programmer because that's off-topic. The entire question itself is fairly borderline in my opinion, but as we do have a precedent for allowing questions about the definition of terminology I didn't close it unilaterally. But since part of it was off-topic and we don't generally want people to ask two different questions in the same post, I removed it.

I think the removal only invalidates two or maybe three of your paragraphs. That said, if you delete the answer it should refund you the reputation (eventually). Although I'm not sure if there is a statute of limitations on that or not, so if you're thinking about it you might want to decide soon.

Answer (score 0):

What @Alexandre suggests is true. The question itself had two problems:

1. It was two completely separate questions with different answers
2. The second part was "How do I get started" kind of question which is not welcome in this community.

So @Josh (one of site moderators), truncated the second part fixing both issues. Obviously it rendered your answer unrelated. and hence you got down-votes.

This was what happened, but to answer your question, you can delete your answer, and you'll get your lost points back. But it might take a while, till the site crawler sees that deleted answer and give back your points. So if you don't get your reputation back instantly, just be patient.

Also as a notice, you might sometimes lose points because of answer/question deletion too. The most likely scenario would be you answering a question, and get a few upvotes for that. If for some reason OP decides to remove that question (or the question is migrated to other channels or ...) you end up losing all the reputation you earned for your answer.

Comment: OP can't delete their own questions when there are upvoted answers, btw.